# setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState) deprecated. What should I do? (Webview plugins)

Tags: android, flash, webview, air

I am making my flash game into an Android app with the following code. It works just fine but the compiler gives the error

> The method setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState) from the type
>   WebSettings is deprecated

Here is the code.

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webview.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);

webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myflashgame.swf");
```

This code works but not for long. How can I achive the same effect? I read that WebView plugins will not be supported in the future. Is there another way to make an app of my flash game?

I heard about Adobe AIR. Is that still supported? Will  it still work in the future?

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you should use AIR to compile your game to an Android app. It is doable using just the [SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html). Google for examples if the ones provided with the SDK are not sufficient.

If you are just starting out it is probably easier to build the app directly from [Flash Builder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-builder.html) by choosing *New* > *ActionScript Mobile Project* and select Android as the target.

Comment: But I only have the .swf file. Can I still do this? Also does AIR apps use flash? Will my app run on every device?

Comment: If you only have the SWF you are out of luck - you need to have the source to create an Android app using AIR. The Android app will not be dependent on the flash runtime on the phone itself - all dependencies will be packaged with the app.