# setPluginsEnabled(true) and setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState) deprecated, what should i do?

Tags: java, android, webview

this code worked fine since I updated to API 19 and the method setPluginsEnabled(true) from the type WebSettings is now deprecated.

I faced that the method setPluginState(PluginState.ON) would be a solution but it is deprecated too.

What could i do? I found these posts [A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21432083/setpluginstatewebsettings-pluginstate-deprecated-what-should-i-do-webview-p), [B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23792642/replacement-of-setpluginsenabled),[C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783035/android-webview-setpluginsenabled-api) that some people had a similar issues, but those answers didnt help me :/
Although the compiler gives me a warning, it compiled successfully. (that's why its going to be deprecated, but it is not yet. Same happened with setPluginEnabled, am I ok?)

Basically what I need to do is show a graphic chart of sells loading the data from a db.

```
private void updateChartDataSet(){
    Enumeration<Integer> enumerator = this.values.keys();
    while(enumerator.hasMoreElements()){
        Integer key = enumerator.nextElement();
        Double value = this.values.get(key);
        this.diasJsonArray.put(DateUtils.convertGraficoVentasMensualDateToString(dateValues.get(key)));
        this.montosJsonArray.put(value);
    }
}

private void setWebViewData(){

    this.webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    this.webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    this.webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    this.webView.addJavascriptInterface(new GraficoWebAppInterface(diasJsonArray,montosJsonArray, "Ventas Mensual", "Venta del día"), "dataLoader");
    this.webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/charts/VentasClientes/chart.html");
    this.webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
            return false;
        }   

    });
```

android_asset/charts/VentasClientes/chart.html:

```html
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="highcharts.js"></script>


<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script>
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: dataLoader.getTittle()
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: eval(dataLoader.getCategories()),
                title: {
                    text: null
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Monto ($)',
                    align: 'high'
                },
                labels: {
                    overflow: 'justify'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
    valueSuffix: '$'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -100,
                y: 100,
                floating: true,
                borderWidth: 1,
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                shadow: true
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: dataLoader.getSerie(),
                data: eval(dataLoader.getData())
            }]
        });
    });
    
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure `setPluginsEnabled` is needed at all? As I can see in highchart's docs, they are purely JS and should use SVG or Canvas, which doesn't require any plugins.

Comment: Since i updated to API 19, the chart is not displayed :/ . "Something" is missing